# How to fix that some letters appear bigger that others in a <h2> element?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, google-chrome

A customer reported an issue where he see the tittles with alternating size of the font. Specially i,m,n,d,a letters are appearing bigger. Like 3 pixels bigger.
See image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mTIJdeIIUXZoOZqsAkJLr_PtR7yXqSTs/view?usp=sharing

To replicate the issue, I've already tried to disable Google Fonts and Angular Fonts, with no results. 
And refresh page. 
Also, restart browser

This is the title:

```
<h2 class="text-center ng-binding" style="margin-top: 20px; font-family: Adamina, serif, google; font-size: 26px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" ng-style="boxTitle[$index].properties" ng-mouseleave="$ctrl.fontColor($index, boxTitle[$index].fontColor)" ng-mouseover="$ctrl.fontColorHover($index, boxTitle[$index].fontColorHover)" ng-bind-html="(box.templateBoxDetails.componentId == 69 &amp;&amp; $ctrl.flagNumberPendingSurveys ? $ctrl.user.patient.totalPendingSurveys + ' ' : '') + box.templateBoxDetails.boxTitle.replace('FirstName', $ctrl.user.firstName)">Welcome to LA Wellness Institute</h2>
```

All letters should appear with the same size. 
And she see some letters bigger than others.

Comment: Did you try to reproduce the issue ?

Comment: It looks very funny ;). If possible ask her to open the same page in Incognito to rule out [1] caching issues and [2] third-party extensions doing it. If the issue is still reproducible ask her to inspect the element in Chrome and send you a screenshot of what the DOM of the element looks like in her browser. You know that styling of specific characters is not possible in CSS hence it may only mean some JavaScript or some alien code doing it. It would really be interesting to see the root cause!

Comment: probably the font is corrupted

Comment: According to https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Adamina:

"Adamina is a typeface designed for text setting in small sizes. For this purpose the x-height is increased and contrast lowered. Proportions are transitional and compact. Refined design features like one-sided flaring and asymmetrical serifs are there to provide a pleasant reading experience."

Seems to me that the font is supposed to be like that and the differences in the x-height are more noticeable with a larger font size.